# Ideal Shard sizing for Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have to setup a multi-node cluster of Clickhouse. I have setup 3 machines for Zookeeper.  Now I have 2 Clickhouse servers with 14 TB Storage each. My question is, how do I setup the number of shards? previously I used to single shard but right now I don't understand what's the best practice is for my infrastructure.

I have used the following configuration before which worked for me. Now with more storage, 14TB each, I don't get what's the best sizing for me.

```
<remote_servers>
    <click_cluster>
        <shard>

            <replica>
                <host>10.10.1.114</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>

            <replica>
                <host>10.10.1.115</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>
        </shard>
    </click_cluster>
</remote_servers>


    <macros>
        <shard>shard-01</shard>
        <replica>replica-01</replica>
    </macros>
```

How should I size my clickhouse ? What If in future I have 2 more Servers to add with same specifications ?

Comment: https://kb.altinity.com/engines/ https://youtu.be/4DlQ6sVKQaA https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/distributed/